# magento model don't save all fields

Tags: magento

This is my model after model->save();

```
[_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 27
            [created_at] => 2016-03-01 23:13:29
            [updated_at] => 2016-03-01 23:13:50
            [name] => 222
            [value] => 222
            [visibility] => 0
            [field] => sponsor
            [page_id] => 21
        )

    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 
    [_origData:protected] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 27
            [created_at] => 2016-03-01 23:13:29
            [updated_at] => 2016-03-01 23:13:29
            [name] => 1234
            [value] => 4321
            [visibility] => 0
            [field] => 
            [page_id] => 0
        )

    [_idFieldName:protected] => entity_id
```

but on my database 'field' and 'page_id' column are not saved. This is my code for save the element:

```
 foreach ($sponsors as $key => $value) {

            $value["field"] = $field;
            $value["page_id"] = $page_id;

            //Mage::Log($value);


            if(intval($key) < 0)
            {
                $a = Mage::getModel('cmsattribute/attribute');
                $a->addData($value);
                $a->save();
            }
            else
            {
                $a = Mage::getModel('cmsattribute/attribute')->load($key);
                $a->addData($value);
                $a->save();
            }


            Mage::Log($a);
        }
```

where can be the problem? name & value are updated, update_ar is also updated, the other 2 field not...

Comment: did you clear the cache? even if the cache is disabled the table schemas are still cached and you might be using an outdated version of the schema.

Answer (score 3):

the field which are not stored in db was old field or have you create new. If it's new please remove all files from var/cache and try to save again.